# Is there a way to keep the weapons between plays in multiplayer?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

Everytime I begin to play the multiplayer online in Red Dead Redemption on my Xbox 360 I begin with some basic weapons. Sometimes during the play and I get a lot of cool weapons and I don't know how to keep them to the next time.

Maybe there is a way to save (since everytime I exit a message warns me about losing all data that is not saved, but I didn't found a way to save, sometimes just autosaves itself).

So, How can I prevent losing all the money and weapons when I quit the game?

Comment: the game autosaves progress at certain points, try doing a a gang hideout before you log off.  I believe there are other things you can do too, but I haven't played in nearly 2 years.

Comment: I think it works similarly to GTA5, in that you unlock weapons as you level up ([see here](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Rank_Unlocks_in_Redemption_Multiplayer)) but you can grab weapons during a multiplayer session and use them temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. When playing multiplayer, at each gang hideout(not dlc) there will be a higher level/rank weapon. You will have any pickups from the game for the session you play in. If you leave the free roam you will lose the pickup weapons. To attain each weapon, you'll have to unlock it via rank. To access them earlier, retrieve your favourite weapons from the corresponding hideout. Also, the explosive rifle will only spawn to tge highestvscoring player in a dlc hideout. It will come with 5 bullets and cannot be replenished via an ammo box. If you die, you lose it.
So when you enter the free roam, go to the gang hideout that has the gun you want, so you can have it for the session.

Comment: Then the answer to the question is **no**? There is not any way to keep the weapons you obtained between plays? You have to start over each time?